# uncrustify wrong newline after member initializer ':'

Tags: c, uncrustify

anybody an idea to avoid the 'wrong' newlines after ':'?
now it looks like this:

```
    *Servo=(APOS_typ){Intern:
                      (APOSINT_typ){CCom:
                                    Servo->Intern.CCom, MasterOf:
                                    Servo->Intern.MasterOf, ClientOf:
                                    Servo->Intern.ClientOf, UpdateTime:
                                    Servo->Intern.UpdateTime, CycAbsMoveParID:
                                    ACP10PAR_USER_I4_VAR1, FromDrive:
                                    Servo->Intern.FromDrive, ToDrive:
                                    Servo->Intern.ToDrive}};
```

i am lookin for something like this:

```
        *Servo=(APOS_typ){Intern : (APOSINT_typ){CCom : Servo->Intern.CCom,
                                                 MasterOf : Servo->Intern.MasterOf,
                                                 ClientOf : Servo->Intern.ClientOf, 
                                                 UpdateTime : Servo->Intern.UpdateTime,
                                                 CycAbsMoveParID : ACP10PAR_USER_I4_VAR1,
                                                 FromDrive : Servo->Intern.FromDrive,
                                                 ToDrive : Servo->Intern.ToDrive}};
```

I couldn't find any parameter for this problem in [default.cfg](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/default.cfg)

Comment: It could have something to do with you not using standard C syntax? See e.g. [this struct/union initialization reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization) for valid designation syntax.

Comment: This is not uncrustify's fault because this is not valid C code.

Comment: Thanx  @Someprogrammerdude for the hint. This is an obsolet gcc extension since GCC 2.5. I didn't recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this was my fault, i was using an old obsolete gcc extension.

the correct struct initialization looks now

```
        *Servo=(APOS_typ){.Intern=(APOSINT_typ){.CCom=Servo->Intern.CCom,
                                                .MasterOf=Servo->Intern.MasterOf,
                                                .ClientOf=Servo->Intern.ClientOf,
                                                .UpdateTime=Servo->Intern.UpdateTime,
                                                .CycAbsMoveParID=ACP10PAR_USER_I4_VAR1,
                                                .FromDrive=Servo->Intern.FromDrive,
                                                .ToDrive=Servo->Intern.ToDrive}};
```

and Uncrustify works well ;-)